# Create a local cache of online DB on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, database, synchronization

I have an online database on Parse for my application. I haven't unlimited API-Request so i want to ask how create a local cache of my database?
When the user do the login, i want to download (sync) all my data and in the app use this data without do more request to Parse.
Any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the parse SDK then it already offers caching. You can set attributes (see `cachePolicy`) on queries to determine how the cache is used.

Alternatively, you could use Core Data (supported by [FTASync](https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync) or [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)).